# Serving LDAPS lookups over HAProxy, unable to bind in testing

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, haproxy

So I've got a sub-domain with a DC that I'm trying to setup HAProxy for SSL termination. So my problem is HAProxy is giving an error in LDP.exe when trying to connect and bind to *ldaps.***tech.com*:

```
Server error: <empty>
53 = ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_ENCRYPT, 1)
res = ldap_bind_s(ld, NULL, &NtAuthIdentity, NEGOTIATE (1158)); // v.3
    {NtAuthIdentity: User='bh-test'; Pwd=<unavailable>; domain = '****tech.com'}
Error <81>: ldap_bind_s() failed: Server Down.
Server error: <empty>
```

I'm able to ping the server just fine, and port 636 is open and waiting. And I'm using creds from a user with Domain Admin perms on that domain.
the HAProxy server is actually feeding two domains with ACLs and the other domain works perfectly.
Here is my Haproxy.cfg:

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    maxconn 2048
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
    #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
    # An alternative list with additional directives can be obtained from
    #  https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=haproxy
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

# Enabling HAProxy Stats
listen  stats
    bind    :8404
        mode    http
        log global
        maxconn 10
        stats enable
        stats refresh 30s
        stats show-node
        stats auth user:password
        stats uri  /haproxy?stats

# LDAPS
frontend ldaps_frontend
  mode                  tcp
  log                   global
  bind                  *:636 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/hap/
  description           LDAPS Service
  option                tcplog
  option                logasap
  option                socket-stats
  option                tcpka
  timeout client        60s
  acl host_j hdr(host) -i j.com
  acl host_*** hdr(host) -i ***tech.com
  use_backend j_ldaps if host_j
  use_backend e*** if host_***

# Enzian Stuff
frontend https-in
  bind          *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/hap/
  mode          http
  description       ***Tech
  option        socket-stats
  default_backend   ***_https
  option        tcplog


backend j_ldaps
  mode          tcp
  balance       leastconn
  server                dc01 x.x.x.x:636 maxconn 100 check ssl fall 1 rise 1 inter 2s verify none check check-ssl
  server                dc02 x.x.x.x:636 maxconn 100 check ssl fall 1 rise 1 inter 2s verify none check check-ssl
  timeout server        60s
  timeout connect       60s
  option                tcpka
  option                tcp-check
  tcp-check             connect port 636 ssl
  tcp-check send-binary 300c0201 # LDAP bind request "<ROOT>" simple
  tcp-check send-binary 01 # message ID
  tcp-check send-binary 6007 # protocol Op
  tcp-check send-binary 0201 # bind request
  tcp-check send-binary 03 # LDAP v3
  tcp-check send-binary 04008000 # name, simple authentication
  tcp-check expect binary 0a0100 # bind response + result code: success
  tcp-check send-binary 30050201034200 # unbind request

backend ***
  mode          tcp
  balance       leastconn
#  server       dc01.***tech.com x.x.x.x:636 maxconn 100 check ssl fall 1 rise 1 inter 2s verify none check check-ssl
  server        dc02.***tech.com x.x.x.x:636 maxconn 100 check ssl fall 1 rise 1 inter 2s verify none check check-ssl
  timeout server    60s
  timeout connect   60s
  option        tcpka
  option        tcp-check
  tcp-check             connect port 636 ssl
  tcp-check send-binary 300c0201 # LDAP bind request "<ROOT>" simple
  tcp-check send-binary 01 # message ID
  tcp-check send-binary 6007 # protocol Op
  tcp-check send-binary 0201 # bind request
  tcp-check send-binary 03 # LDAP v3
  tcp-check send-binary 04008000 # name, simple authentication
  tcp-check expect binary 0a0100 # bind response + result code: success
  tcp-check send-binary 30050201034200 # unbind request

backend ***_https
  mode          http
  balance       leastconn
  server        subca02.***tech.com x.x.x.x:443 maxconn 100 check ssl fall 1 rise 1 inter 2s verify none check check-ssl
#  server       dc01.***tech.com x.x.x.x:636 maxconn 100 check ssl fall 1 rise 1 inter 2s verify none check check-ssl
  option        httpchk OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
```

The credentials used have been dbl-checked, there is no local firewall on this DC, no firewalls between either host so I'm rather lost.
Any advice is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hdr(host)` ist for http workload and makes no sends with **mode tcp**.
[hdr()](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/configuration.html#7.3.6-hdr)

I would try to use `req.ssl_sni` for routing as described in [How does the SNI Routing works in HAProxy](https://www.me2digital.com/blog/2019/05/haproxy-sni-routing/) and [Enhanced SSL Load Balancing with Server Name Indication (SNI) TLS Extension](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/enhanced-ssl-load-balancing-with-server-name-indication-sni-tls-extension/)

Here the untested snipplet

```
frontend ldaps_frontend
  mode                  tcp
  log                   global
  bind                  *:636 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/hap/
  description           LDAPS Service
  option                tcplog
  option                logasap
  option                socket-stats
  option                tcpka
  timeout client        60s

  acl host_j   req.ssl_sni -i j.com
  acl host_*** req.ssl_sni -i ***tech.com

  use_backend j_ldaps if host_j
  use_backend e*** if host_***
```

Comment: Thank you Aleksandar.. according to the Haproxy doc this won't work with bind lines that include SSL.  In fact reading most of the req.ssl options won't work with that.  Testing it, it in fact does now allow me to bind using LDP.exe from a testing client.

Comment: You did point me in the right direction. req.ssl_sni is depricated however the example on the official docs does seem to be working... mostly. Since I'm in a most working status and my actual issue has change I'm going to award you and post another more directed question. Thanks and sorry for teh lateness.