# HAProxy SSL passthrough and ACL rules not working

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to get SSL passthrough working so only my backends need SSL and not the HAProxy frontends.

I also want to use ACL rules to only allow certain domains to get sent to the backend and those that do not match will get another backend.

So far I have this, but it seems to not be working:

```
global
        log /dev/log local0
        log /dev/log local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon
        maxconn 10240
        nbproc 4
        nbthread 1
        cpu-map auto:1/1-4 0-3

defaults
        log global
        mode http
        option httplog
        option dontlognull
        maxconn 2048
        retries 3
        timeout connect 10s
        timeout client  30s
        timeout server  30s
        timeout http-request 10s
        timeout http-keep-alive 2s
        timeout queue 5s
        timeout tunnel 2m
        timeout client-fin 2s
        timeout server-fin

frontend abc.com
         bind AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:80
         bind AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:443
         acl ValidDomain hdr_dom(host) -i abc.com
         use_backend abc.com if ValidDomain
         default_backend fallback

backend abc.com
         balance static-rr
         server default ZZZ.YYY.XXX.WWW:443 ssl check verify none

backend fallback
         balance static-rr
         server fallback 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Can anyone figure out why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the `mode tcp` instead of `mode http` and the can your route based on SNI.

You can get a example solution in this answer [Serving LDAPS lookups over HAProxy, unable to bind in testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67645014/serving-ldaps-lookups-over-haproxy-unable-to-bind-in-testing/67849001#67849001)